# "Подписать документ" или "расписаться на документе"?

Tags: стилистика

Какое выражение верно: "Подписать документ" или "Расписаться на документе"?

Answer (score 1):

*Подпись* — 1) собственноручно написанная фамилия: сличить подпись, поставить подпись; 2) надпись под чем-либо: подписи под рисунком.

*Роспись* —  1) орнаментальная или сюжетная живопись, украшающая различные части архитектурного сооружения либо предметы, изделия народного искусства, художественного ремесла или художественной промышленности: архитектурная роспись; роспись керамики; федоскинская, палехская, мстёрская, холуйская, жостовская, тагильская роспись по лаку; хохломская роспись; 2) распределение чего-либо, перечень: роспись расходов.

Таким образом, собственноручное начертание фамилии должностного лица — это *подпись,* правильно: *подписать документ.*

Answer (score 1):

"Расписаться на документе" — тоже правильно. Одно из значений слова "расписаться" — поставить свою подпись, удостоверяя что-либо. Но в официальных документах надо употреблять выражение "подписать документ".

Answer (score 0):

Подписать документ - стилистически правильно. 
Пример: Руководитель подписал документ. Все присутствующие на собрании подписали документ. Подпишите данный документ.
Расписаться в документе - допустимо с предлогом "в", но никак не с предлогом "на", т.е. "расписаться на документе" - неправильно.
Пример: Распишитесь в данном документе. Все присутствующие расписались в документе.